# How do I run Python code for my function calculations in my Swift software App?

Tags: python, ios, swift

I am creating an app where the user inputs two values (x and y).
These two values are used in a function to output an answer that is displayed at the bottom of the app. 
These calculations include gaussian covariance calculations, so they must be done in my Python script, which will result in one final value to be outputted.
Can I connect this Python file in a Swift app?

I know how to create an Xcode project that is an external file that can connect with python, but how do I do this in my Swift project I have already built?

Comment: You will have to host the python code on a server and call it over the web.

Answer (score 1):

**Implement the algorithm in Swift**

I don't think a covariance would be particularly hard to do and if you implement it in the open source [Upsurge](https://github.com/aleph7/Upsurge) library you will get **unbelievably better performance** as it uses the Accelerate Framework (i.e. specially tuned calls to SIMD that Apple engineers have spent a lot of time on).

I added [linear regression](https://github.com/aleph7/Upsurge/blob/master/Source/Operations/Arithmetic.swift) to Upsurge and it is at least an order of magnitude faster than the Python/Numpy code running on the same machine.

Comment: Thanks for the help! But my Python file involves more than just the covariance function, so I do not think I can put the code into swift. Do you know any way to run the python script through swift?

Comment: If you completely and utterly reject the idea of implementing it in Swift, your only alternative is to make it available on a server somewhere via presumably a JSON call. But this will be dramatically higher latency than a local implementation because you have to query and respond over a network.

Comment: You are right, I am going to implement it all in swift. I downloaded the three main folders in Upsurge (Source, Supporting Files, Tests), but I am still getting a build fail of "No such module 'Upsurge' " in different Test swift files. Do you know how I can fix this? Thanks for all your help!